# Pdal and Earth Curvature/which EPSG

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, epsg, usgs, pdal

I am attempting to combine Lidar data that we capture using a scanner (which is real-world accurate) and USGS Lidar data. I am currently using Pdal and Entwine to download and reproject the section of USGS data I would like to use.

The problem I am foreseeing is that all the reprojections are still based on flat maps and don't take into account the curvature of the earth and how that would affect the height information. Is there a method in Pdal or other library/software that will correctly apply earth curvature to flat map derived Lidar data?

There might even be a way to apply a custom transformation to the data that would curve the position of the points based on the center of the bounding box?

Mostly I would ignore this distortion since we don't deal with large enough data sets that the loss of the correct horizon would cause a problem. But we want to potentially use mountains and other distant/large features accurately.

Comment: Are the heights ellipsoid-based or gravity-based (e.g., elevations, heights above geoid surface)?

Comment: I'm not sure. The current USGS LAS I'm looking at uses the 2227 EPSG [EPSG Description](https://epsg.io/2227). Where would be a good place look up/research this kind of information?